# Calling method to provide search parameters in Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, controller

I've got a Rails controller with the following pieces:

```
def search
  ...
  @player_to_team_histories = @player_to_team_histories.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
  ...
```

`sort_column` and `sort_direction` are defined as (`@player_to_team_histories` is an `ActiveRecordAssociation`:

```
private

  def sort_column
    params[:sort] || "players.LastName"
  end

  def sort_direction
    params[:direction] || "asc"
  end
```

So the text returned from those two functions gets inserted into the `order` clause on the `@player_to_team_histories`.

I need to duplicate this search functionality in another controller, so I've moved the search logic to the `PlayerToTeamHistories` model and pass the `params` hash as a parameter to the `search` function.  Skeleton code:

```
def self.search_results(params)
 ...
  @player_to_team_histories = @player_to_team_histories.order(sort_column(params) + " " + sort_direction(params))
 ...
```

I tried defining `sort_column(params)` and `sort_direction(params)` in a module and kept getting an `undefined method or variable sort_columns` error, so I moved the implementation to the bottom of the model

```
def sort_column(params)
  params[:sort] || "players.LastName"
end

def sort_direction(params)
  params[:direction] || "asc"
end
```

And still get the undefined method error.  I tried simplifying it to:

```
def sort_column
  "players.LastName"
end

def sort_direction
  "asc"
end
```

But that still didn't work (I updated the call to the functions to be without `params`).

Any idea why I can't call a helper function from within another function in a model?

Rails 3.2.1, Ruby 1.9.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the methods are in the model - they're instance ones. You should call them as:

```
def self.search_results(params)
 ...
  @player_to_team_histories = @player_to_team_histories.order(@player_to_team_histories.sort_column + " " + @player_to_team_histories.sort_direction)
 ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks! As a side note, are controller methods special in some way? (i.e. Why do I not need to call self.sort_column in a controller?).

Comment: no - controller methods are not special. Test it out and post an example so we could work off of. One more thing - if you want controller methods available to more than one controller, you could either define a parent controller (Inheriting from ApplicationController) with those methods defined and inherit from it; or define your methods in application_controller.rb. But I think these are more model methods.

Comment: I think it has to do with instance variables, as you pointed out.  When you are in a controller action (say, `index`), I think you are given an instance of that controller, so the `self` is implicit.  Thanks for the help